# Is 'rather + pronoun + root-verb' pattern possible?

Tags: modal-verbs, verb-forms, semi-modals

> I had much rather we not stay. ([Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rather?s=t))
>  I'd rather you
>   didn't go out alone. ([Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/rather))

If the first sentence is possible, I guess, the second one can be re-write as “I’d rather you not go out alone." Is this really possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SHORT ANSWER:**
Yes, that rewrite is perfectly acceptable. It is however ‘rather’ (in the ‘somewhat’ sense) an old-fashioned way of expressing it.

**LONGER (BUT STILL NOT NEARLY LONG ENOUGH) ANSWER:**
Expressions with *rather* are quite complicated, because they are really ‘fossils’ from earlier states of the language. Some of the issues involved are:

- The *had* in your first example is the full verb, not an auxiliary. Grammatically it is a rare instance of the past form representing contingency or unreality outside a conditional construction. Today we express this grammatically almost exclusively as *would have*; but well into the 18th century the form (which it is hard not to call ‘subjunctive’) sometimes represented the sense ‘to desire or wish [someone to do something]’ (*I had rather that ye never maryed in yowyr lyffe - 1478*)  and at other times the sense ‘to experience or suffer’ (*He had better been drowned - 1665*).
- The *’d* in your second example would be understood by most speakers as a contraction not of *had* but of *would*, which since the middle of the 18th century has been far more usual than *had* with *rather*:

  [image]

  That *would*, again, represents what is now a fairly rare use: although its past form does as usual express the ‘subjunctive’ sense of contingency or unreality, the base sense is volitive, *wish* or *want*. (*Would that it were so!*)
- The verb forms in the complement are also archaic in the cases which employ what you call the ‘root-verb’. I suspect you are being very diplomatic and carefully avoiding calling it either an ‘infinitive’ or a ‘subjunctive’; if you are not, you should be, because sometimes it is definitely an infinitive and at other times it may be called either infinitive or subjunctive.

  - Without a pronoun, expressing what the subject would rather do, it is definitely an unmarked infinitive, the final verb in the verbal chain of the main clause, not a component of a subordinate clause; this is possible only with the *would* version, which is grammatically an ordinary modal:

    > He would rather be dead.  *derived from* He would be dead [=*He wants to be dead*] *derived from* He will be dead.
  - But with a pronoun, expressing either what the subject would rather do himself or what he would rather someone else do, the verb is a component of a subordinate *that-clause*. Grammarians differ over whether this should be called an infinitive or a mandative subjunctive:

    > I had/would rather [that] you be dead than that you marry her.
  - In any case, the version with the past form—“I would rather you **were** dead”—has been preferred at least since the early 19th century:

  [image]

  - That version of course, must be inverted in a negative, and needs *DO-support* if the tensed verb is not *BE* or an auxiliary:

    > I would rather you did not marry her.

So the more frequent use would be that with the past form and *DO-support: “I'd rather you didn't go out alone. “

Comment: In fact, I used 'subjuctive,' in WR, but was declined. Now, I'm out all through the vague tunnel.